# Implementing date sort (day, month, year) with quicksort in C++

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

I tried to sort the dates by implementing quicksort myself. However, the sample output is correct, but when I submit the correct answer, it says incorrect. I don't know where I'm going wrong, so I'm asking this question.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

void swap(std::vector<Date>& vec, int a, int b)
{
    Date temp = vec[a];
    vec[a] = vec[b];
    vec[b] = temp;
}
void func(std::vector<Date>& vec, int a, int b)
{
    if (vec[a].year > vec[b].year)
    {
        swap(vec, a, b);
    }
    else if (vec[a].year == vec[b].year && vec[a].month > vec[b].month)
    {
        swap(vec, a, b);
    }
    else if (vec[a].year == vec[b].year && vec[a].month == vec[b].month && vec[a].day > vec[b].day)
    {
        swap(vec, a, b);
    }
}

int partition(std::vector<Date>& vec, int left, int right, int index)
{
    int pivot;
    int value;

    if (index == 2)              // Year is year, month is month, day is day to day, the pivot is initialized by putting an if statement to compare.
        pivot = vec[right].year;
    if (index == 1)
        pivot = vec[right].month;
    if (index == 0)
        pivot = vec[right].day;

    int i = left - 1;

    for (int j = left; j <= right - 1; j++)
    {
        if (index == 2)
            value = vec[j].year;
        if (index == 1)
            value = vec[j].month;
        if (index == 0)
            value = vec[j].day;

        if (value <= pivot)
        {
            i++;

            func(vec, i, j);
        }
    }
    func(vec, i + 1, right);

    return i + 1;
}
void quick_sort(std::vector<Date>& vec, int left, int right, int index)
{
    if (left < right)
    {
        int p = partition(vec, left, right, index);
        quick_sort(vec, left, p - 1, index);
        quick_sort(vec, p + 1, right, index);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int num;
    Date date;

    std::cin >> num; // 1≤ num ≤500,000
    std::vector<Date> vec(num);

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> vec[i].day >> vec[i].month >> vec[i].year;
    }

    quick_sort(vec, 0, vec.size() - 1, 2); // In order to sort by year, index 2 is added to the quick function.
    quick_sort(vec, 0, vec.size() - 1, 1); // In order to sort by month, index 1 is added to the quick function.
    quick_sort(vec, 0, vec.size() - 1, 0); // In order to sort by day, index01 is added to the quick function.

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << vec[i].day << " " << vec[i].month << " " << vec[i].year << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample input 1

```txt
6
20 1 2014
25 3 2010
3 12 2001
18 11 2001
19 4 2015
9 7 2005
```

Sample output

```txt
18 11 2001
3 12 2001
9 7 2005
25 3 2010
20 1 2014
19 4 2015
```

My output also came out with the sample output, but the problem submission site says it's wrong.

```cpp
void func(std::vector<Date>& vec, int a, int b)
{
    if (vec[a].year > vec[b].year)
    {
        swap(vec, a, b);
    }
    else if (vec[a].year == vec[b].year && vec[a].month > vec[b].month)
    {
        swap(vec, a, b);
    }
    else if (vec[a].year == vec[b].year && vec[a].month == vec[b].month && vec[a].day > vec[b].day)
    {
        swap(vec, a, b);
    }
}
```

Maybe something went wrong when calling func from the partition function? Or is the logic wrong in the func function?

Comment: You could have written a Date class with comparison operators, then sort your dates in one go.

Comment: There are some obvious edge cases with Quicksort. 1. The pivot is the smallest member of the vector. 2. The pivot is the largest member of the vector. 3. Two or more identical elements in the vector. 4. The pivot has another identical element elsewhere in the vector.  5. Single element vector.  6. Empty vector. Make sure your test cases cover all of those.